# Which staff does the dynamic apply to

Tags: sheet-music, dynamics

The dynamic is in between the two staves, so does it apply to the upper staff, lower staff or both staves? [image]

Comment: Note, notations software might vary on how it interprets this during playback. I've used one that couldn't actually put dynamics between the staves; I had to attach it to one and then drag into the middle position. Also, of course in this exact example, one staff has rests...